# Why does the Eclipse code formatter break </a> in a Javadoc @see tag?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc, eclipse-3.4

I'm using Eclipse 3.4 and have configured the Java code formatter with all of the options on the *Comments* tab enabled. The problem is that when I format a document comment that contains:

```
* @see <a href="test.html">test</a>
```

the code formatter inserts a space in the closing HTML, breaking it:

```
* @see <a href="test.html">test< /a>
```

Why? How do I stop this happening?

This is not fixed by disabling any of the options on the *Comments* tab, such as *Format HTML tags*. The only work-around I found is to disable Javadoc formatting completely by disabling both the *Enable Javadoc comment formatting* and *Enable block comment formatting* options, which means I then have to format comment blocks manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only assume it's a bug in Eclipse. It only happens with *@see* tags, it happens also for all 3 builtin code formatter settings.

There are some interesting bugs reported already in the neighbourhood, but I couldn't find this specific one. See for example a search for *@see* in the [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__all__&product=JDT&content=%40see).

Answer (score 1):

Strict XML specifications require that the self closing tags should have a space before the closing slash like so:

```
<gcServer enabled="true" /> <!-- note the space just after "true" -->
```

I can only assume, like Bart said, that there is a bug in Eclipse's reformatter that thinks the closing tag is actually a self-closing tag. Another idea: Can you verify that your **a** tags are balanced (i.e. no unclosed tags higher up in the document)?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug in Eclipse 3.4.  I'm using 3.3 (M20080221-1800), and do not observe this behavior.